# Clojure / HBase: How to Import HBaseTestingUtility in v0.94.6.1

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, hbase

In Clojure, if I want to start a test cluster using the hbase testing utility, I have to annotate my dependencies with:

```
[org.apache.hbase/hbase "0.92.2" :classifier "tests" :scope "test"]
```

First of all, I have no idea what this means.  According to leiningens sample project.clj

```
;; Dependencies are listed as [group-id/name version]; in addition
;; to keywords supported by Pomegranate, you can use :native-prefix
;; to specify a prefix. This prefix is used to extract natives in
;; jars that don't adhere to the default "<os>/<arch>/" layout that
;; Leiningen expects.
```

Question 1: What does that mean?

Question 2: If I upgrade the version:

```
[org.apache.hbase/hbase "0.94.6.1" :classifier "tests" :scope "test"]
```

Then I receive a ClassNotFoundException

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
```

Whats going on here and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

any key / value pairs added to a dependency declaration are used as arguments to the clojure pomegranate library

the keys recognized are listed in the source here: [in the source to pomagranate](https://github.com/cemerick/pomegranate/blob/master/src/main/clojure/cemerick/pomegranate/aether.clj#L489) (for future reference that is a link to the function resolve-artifacts*)

[the maven pom docs may also be helpful](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html)

:scope describes the conditions where the dependency is used, so :scope "test" would seem to indicate that the dependency is only pulled in while testing

:classifier seems to indicate the an extra element distinguishing versions

I speculate that the dependency resolution for the newer hbase version may have a poorly configured pom which is not declaring its dependencies properly. Try finding the info for org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration and requiring the package manually.

Answer (score 1):

Leinigen uses the [Maven dependency mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope). Read that link to understand that different scopes.

The "classifier" is a token that is part of the dependency coordinates, so that a group of Jars / zip files / etc. can be part of the same logic release, but declared as distinct dependencies in your pom.xml.  So in this case "tests" is a distinct HBase artifact from 0.94.6.1 that contains the tests.

You can see this in action by pointing your browser to the Maven "Central" repo location for that version of HBase:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hbase/hbase/0.94.6.1/

You can search the maven "central" repo here:

https://repository.apache.org/

or

http://mvnrepository.com/

On `ClassNotFOundException` - agreed with noisesmith. Your best bet is to find the dependency (jar) that contains that class and explicitly add it to your project dependency configuration.

Usually I do a google search for the classname and "jar" i.e. 
https://www.google.com/search?q=jar+org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration